# Java - Is it ok to instantiate class objects inside class?

Tags: java, static, static-variables

Have I done some kind of design mistake?

I have made a abstract class to represent fractal sets, and decided to instantiate some of them in the same class file. However I've noticed I can access all of the Fractal objects from each one of them, because everyone of them is an instance of a class extended from Fractal. See this example:

```
public abstract class Fractal {
    double x; // default x
    double y; // default y
    double zoom;
    String name;

    public abstract double zreal(double a, double b);

    public abstract double zimag(double a, double b);

    public abstract void setup();

    public Fractal() {
        setup();
    }

    ////// FRACTALS DEFINITIONS ///////

    public static Fractal mandelbrot = new Fractal() {

        @Override
        public double zreal(double a, double b) {
            return a * a - b * b;
        }

        @Override
        public double zimag(double a, double b) {
            return 2 * a * b;
        }

        @Override
        public void setup() {
            name = "Mandelbrot Z'=Z^2+C";
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            zoom = 1;
        }
    };
}
```

With this setup I can do something like this with no error:

```
Fractal f = Fractal.mandelbrot.mandelbrot.mandelbrot.mandelbrot.mandelbrot;
```

So I'm wondering if this means there is some kind of design mistake I've made instantiating Fractal objects inside Fractal class, and that's why I'm asking your help. A lot of thanks.

Comment: You do realize that `Fractal.mandelbrot.mandelbrot.mandelbrot.mandelbrot.mandelbrot == Fractal.mandelbrot`, right? You're accessing a static member as if it were an instance member, and doing it multiple times for absolutely no reason. A more relevant design question IMHO is, should `mandelbrot` really be (just) an anonymous subclass of `Fractal` as you've written?